# How to deploy Django on IIS with git hooks using virtenv on a remote Windows server?

Tags: django, git, iis

I successfully installed and setup Django (2.0.2) using Python 3.6.4 on IIS on a remote Windows Server 2012 R2 (in a VPN environment) accordingly to this instruction:

- http://blog.mattwoodward.com/2016/07/running-django-application-on-windows.html

I'm using SQL Server as backend and I stored the sensitive data such as the `DJANGO_SECRET_KEY`, `DATABASE_PASSWORD` etc. as environment variables in the `FastCGI Settings` at the IIS (see the above link, section *Configure FastCGI in IIS* step 14)

At this point I asked me, how to deploy my apps and do all the necessary setps like install packages from `requirements.txt`, `collectstatic`, `makemigrations` etc.

With googleing I found a possible solution using git hooks, especially a post-receive hook accordingly to this post:

- https://dylanwooters.wordpress.com/2015/02/21/one-command-deployments-to-iis-using-git/

So I successfully setup Bonobo Git Server on the same IIS accordingly to this instruction:

- https://bonobogitserver.com/install/

My thought was to put all the required commands into this post-receive hook file as I would do in the development environment. I ended up with this file at location `\inetpub\wwwroot\Bonobo.Git.Server\App_Data\Repositories\myapp-master\hooks\post-receive`:

```
#!/bin/sh
DEPLOYDIR=/c/apps/myapp
VIRTENVDIR=/c/virtualenvs/myapp
GIT_WORK_TREE="$DEPLOYDIR" git checkout -f
cd $VIRTENVDIR
source Scripts/activate
cd $DEPLOYDIR
pip install -r requirements.txt
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

I grant permission to the `Scripts/activate` file and I receive no erros during `push` from my development environment. But the current problem is that the command at line 6 doesn't activate the virtual environment and therefore no migrations etc. happens. Normally I would activate the virtual environment with the command line prompt using these commands:

```
cd C:\virtualenvs\myapp
Scripts\activate.bat
```

but I can't use this in the post-reveive file because it uses unix-based commands.

Can anyone help me or have a better idea how to deploy in a nicer way in a windows environment without going into the cloud?